# Question on slow decay to $\;0\;$ at infinity of a function

Tags: calculus, functions, multivariable-calculus, improper-integrals

> Let $\;f\;: \mathbb R^m \rightarrow [0, \infty)\;$ be a continuous
>   function and $\;g:[M,+\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb R\;$ a non-negative
>   $\;L_{loc}^1\;$ function, where $\;M \gt 0\;$ such that $\;
>  \int_{M}^{\infty} g(s) \;ds=+\infty\;$.
>
> If this holds:
>
> $\;\sqrt {f(x)} \ge g(\vert x \vert )\;\;\forall x:\;\vert x \vert \ge
>  M\;$ **(*)**,
>
> then one can say $\;f\;$ decays slow to $\;0\;$ at infinity.

**Why is this true?**

I thought of setting $\;g(x)=\frac {1}{\sqrt x}\;$ to **(*)** . Then I get $\;f(x) \ge \frac {1}{\vert x \vert}\;\;\forall x:\;\vert x \vert \ge M\; \Rightarrow \int_{M}^{\infty} f(x)\;dx \ge \int_{M}^{\infty} \frac {1}{\vert x \vert}\;dx =+\infty  $

However it's still unclear to me how this connects to the behaviour of $\;f\;$ at infinity.
**Does the fact that $\;\int_{M}^{\infty} f(x)\;dx \ge +\infty\;$ imply somehow $\;f\;$ slow decays to $\;0\;$?**

I 'm really new to fast or slow decay of a function, so I apologize in advance if my question is trivial or quite elementary. Any help would be valuable.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the definition of "decays slow to $0$ at infinity"?

Comment: @User8128 What do you mean? I don't have a certain definition in mind nor in my notes...

Comment: Then this question is ill-posed. How do you expect an answer when some terms in the definition are undefined?

Comment: @User8128 Excuse me but this is the first time (strangely enough) I see about slow or fast decay...This is what exactly my professor told us in class, so I haven't any definitions. What kind of  different definitions of "decays to 0 at infinity" exist?

Comment: I have no idea. I've also never seen that term (and I ascertain by the lack of response, that others likely have not seen that term either). You should certainly get come clarification.

Comment: @User8128 I will, thank you